# Synonym for "aforementioned" without the past-tense connotation

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, past-participles

Is there a word that can be used when discussing something and wanting to refer to it in the manner of "the aforementioned", but without the temporal aspect making it sound like you've moved on and are referring back to it?  The item under discussion is the *current* matter-at-hand and I'd like a word with the feel of "aforementioned", but the present-tense of "matter-at-hand" or "current subject matter".

For example, when discussing someone's statement/idea/syllogism, I don't want to say so-and-so's aforementioned statement, because it's the current subject matter that we're presently discussing.

Comment: Just say so-and-so’s statement, then.

Comment: Did you look at a thesaurus? Were those not good enough?

Comment: *Aforementioned* and similar phrases don't make it sound like you've moved on. You don't need a different word. And if it's all that current, you don't need *aforementioned*, either -- just "Jones' statement/idea/syllogism".

Comment: *Mentioned herewithin* ;-)

Comment: Just leave out "aforementioned". You can say "As Jack argued" or "Jack's statement".

Comment: @Mitch, I did look in a few thesauri but didn't find anything that worked.

Comment: @SF., I like that one, but it seems I was so lost in the business of making a cohesive argument and qualifying all my statements that I overlooked the obvious that tchrist, StoneyB, and David pointed out. No qualifying adjective is necessary, just say "so-and-so's statement".  So who wants to put that in the form of an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: @Travis: I put the `;-)` at the end for a reason. It's so abhorrent you'd need to be a despicable pretentious snob, or even worse, a lawyer, to use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sense of previousness in "aforementioned" is specifically in the sense of "appears before" and not "occurred before"; so, I would argue that using it is fine in the circumstances you described.

I find that it can often be effective to use more explicit, than general, constructs; these give a writer much more flexibility in setting the tone, or conveying something implicit, such as tense. Instead of:

> ...so-and-so's aforementioned statement

Alternative constructs could be used:

> ...as so-and-so states
>   So-and-so states that...
>   The statement that so-and-so makes is...

Which allows you to emphasise the present-tenseness of the referred-to statement, as compared to: *"as so-and-so stated"*, etc. There are any number of variations to this approach that you can use, as per your taste, and depending on what nuance you want to convey. You can build in as many implicit nuances as you like, using this approach. For instance:

> The core premise of so-and-so's position, as can be derived from close examination of his/her (aforementioned statement/statement regarding X), is that...

Answer (score 2):

If the  statement/idea/syllogism is the most-recently-mentioned thing, pronouns like *this* and *that* will serve.  For example, with A and B conversing, if A says  “Clearly X because of Y”, B might reply as follows, and any of the replies shown would be understood as referring to A's statement:

> But this supposes Z applies.
>   But that supposes Z applies.
>   But that statement supposes Z applies.

When B wants to comment on a less-recent statement, B might need to say explicitly what statement is referred to, perhaps by quoting part of it.  Eg, “When you said P, you forgot about Q”.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be *foregoing*.

However, I myself would avoid a direct reference altogether. In stead, I might restate the point in a short way or by rephrasing it (as if to recap).

*fore·go·ing* /fôrˈgōiNG/
adj. *Just mentioned or stated; preceding*.
n. *The things just mentioned or stated*.
syn. *previous - antecedent - preceding - former - anterior*

[*Foregoing*](http://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/foregoing.php) is used in writing to refer to things that have been stated before what is currently being stated.
"We have examined the foregoing report and can attest to its validity. (*aforementioned*) "